chandra, bruhaspati and his wife Tara
I have read this story of chandra and Tara, wife of deva guru, bruhaspati. It is kind of hard to digest despite soma and bruhaspati considered as divine. What is this story trying to tell? Why did tara fell for chandra? , how did chandra attract tara? weren't they supposed to overcome their pleasures? It is wrong, isn't it? what is the paramartha behind this story?
